# How do we call neo4j 3.4 database uri from java?

Tags: java, neo4j

I have upgraded my neo4j from 2.3 to 3.4. Initially I had used WebTarget to connect the same. Now its been changed to bolt URI. While trying to connect with bolt://localhost:7687, I am getting an error like "javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bolt". How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you certain that you are using URI instead of URL? This occurs mostly because of using URL with bolt.

Comment: I had tried to connect with the URI instead of URL since bolt is being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this in your Configuration Neo4j class:

 @Bean
    public Driver neo4jDriver() {

        Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://127.0.0.1:7687",
                AuthTokens.basic(<user>, <pass>));

        return driver;

    }
```